# What is the most minimalistic way for CLI search and replace using part of matched strings?

Tags: regex, perl, vim, awk, sed

I have a few Ruby files with some hashes indexed by symbols which are fed into elasticsearch. They are returned from queries indexed by strings. I want to replace all of these with symbols.

What is the best command for the minimal use of this?

I tried doing something like `'a'bs/\v:[a-z_]+/\='submatch(0)'/g`and had some trouble (doesn't work).

Out of awk, sed, perl, or whatever other commonly available tool, how would you accomplish this in as few character as possible while being elegant?
(I don't consider `submatch(0)` elegant.)

Comment: post an example along with expected output.

Comment: A simpler version of what it looks like you are trying is the following but I really have no idea if thats right... `:s/\v:[a-z_]+/'&'/g`

Comment: I need to strip off the preceeding semicolon in & though.

Comment: without showing us sample input and expected output any answer you get might not be the best (or even an appropriate) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to turn `:symbol` into `'symbol'`. If so you can use a capture group to do this

```
:s/\v:([a-z_]+)/'\1'/g
```

where everything in parentheses is the first capture group referenced by `\1`